# Como eu posso alterar a versão do C no MinGw?

Tags: c

Eu comecei a estudar C recentemente, e ao tentar "dinamicamente" setar o tamanho de um Vetor através de uma variável recebo o seguinte erro:

**error: ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'vetor' [-Wvla]**

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int tam=0;
    scanf("%d",&tam);
    int vetor[tam];
    return 0;
}
```

Andei pesquisando e é possível alterar a versão do C utilizada pelo compilador, só não sei como.

Comment: Esta feature só foi incorpora no C99. Faça download de https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/ ou o próprio `gcc` de https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/

Comment: Isso não é algo importante. Provavelmente você estaria melhor alocando `tam` bytes via `malloc()` ou usando um valor fixo que considere suficiente. Em geral programas para iniciantes que leêm o tamanho do vetor via usuário também vão ler os valores via teclado, e ninguém vai digitar de fato mais que uma meia dúzia de valores... VLA pode ser importante em algum contexto, mas quando isso for importante para você por certo não será mais um iniciante e saberá o que fazer

Comment: A função de inserir o tamanho do vetor diretamente foi implementada no C99, eu consegui forçar o minGw a compilar nesta versão usando o comando "-std=c99" pelo CMD.
Edit: eu estava precisando pra resolver uma questão que necessitava especificamente que o usuário inserisse o tamanho do vetor,  embora eu esteja começando na linguagem, não tive muita escolha. Porém muito obrigado. :)